Unable to create the Pipeline with Data FLow using Java SDK
We are trying to create a Pipeline with a dataflow activity which is performing one aggregation operation.
While implementing we are using the below structure and dependencies,
SDK Version: com.azure.resourcemanager:azure-resourcemanager-datafactory:1.0.0-beta.30
We want Data flow pipeline to be visible on UI with appropriate data flow activity through above Java SDK.
As DataFlowActivity is not there in SDK what will be the alternative approach to display pipelines created through Java code on UI.
Note: Not able to create "CustomActivity" as "withName" and multiple methods are not accessible.
Code Snippet:
    LinkedServiceReference linkedServiceReference =new LinkedServiceReference()
            .withReferenceName(linkedServiceName);

    // Create Source Dataset
    AzureBlobDataset sourceDataset = new AzureBlobDataset()
            .withLinkedServiceName(linkedServiceReference)
            .withFolderPath(bronzeContainerName)
            .withFileName(p0FileName);

    // Create Destination Dataset
    AzureBlobDataset destinationDataset = new AzureBlobDataset()
            .withLinkedServiceName(linkedServiceReference)
            .withFolderPath(goldContainerName)
            .withFileName(p0JsonFileName);

    // Create the datasets
    DatasetResource p0SourceDataSet = dataFactoryManager.datasets().define("p0SourceDataSet")
            .withExistingFactory(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName)
            .withProperties(sourceDataset)
            .create();

    DatasetResource p0DestinationDataSet = dataFactoryManager.datasets().define("p0DestinationDataSet")
            .withExistingFactory(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName)
            .withProperties(destinationDataset)
            .create();

    // Sink
    DatasetReference datasetReference = new DatasetReference()
            .withReferenceName("p0DestinationDataSet");

    DataFlowSink sink =  new DataFlowSink()
            .withName("P0Sink")
            .withDataset(datasetReference);

    // Create Data Flow
    MappingDataFlow mappingDataFlow =new MappingDataFlow()
            .withDescription("Vianova Data Flow")
            .withSinks(Collections.singletonList(sink));

    DataFlowSource source = new DataFlowSource()
            .withName("source")
            .withDataset(new DatasetReference().withReferenceName("p0SourceDataSet"));

    mappingDataFlow.withSources(Collections.singletonList(source));

    DataFlowResource dataFlowResource = dataFactoryManager.dataFlows().define("vianovaDataFlow")
            .withExistingFactory(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName)
            .withProperties(mappingDataFlow)
            .create();

    // Create DataFlowReference
    DataFlowReference dataFlowReference = new DataFlowReference()
            .withType(DataFlowReferenceType.fromString("VianovaDataFlowReference"))  // Setting the type explicitly to "MappingDataFlow"
            .withReferenceName(dataFlowResource.name()); // Reference the data flow you just created


    ExecuteDataFlowActivity executeDataFlowActivity =new ExecuteDataFlowActivity()
            .withName("Vianova Data Activity")
            .withDataFlow(dataFlowReference); // Set the data flow reference

    // Create Pipeline
    PipelineResource pipelineResource = dataFactoryManager.pipelines().define("VianovaSamplePipeline")
            .withExistingFactory(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName)
            .withDescription("Vianova P file Transformation Pipeline")
            .withActivities(Collections.singletonList(executeDataFlowActivity))
            .create();

    CreateRunResponse run = pipelineResource.createRun();

Error:
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Pipeline Entity not valid",
"target": "Pipeline/VianovaSamplePipeline",
"details": null
}
}": Pipeline Entity not valid] with root cause
com.azure.core.management.exception.ManagementException: Status code 400, "{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Pipeline Entity not valid",
"target": "Pipeline/VianovaSamplePipeline",
"details": null
}
}"
Expecting a pipeline to be created with dataflow mapping

Can you edit and add your pipeline, linked service and dataflow JSONs? you can mask your credentials.
